# NSJSONSerialization - Core Data relationships to JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I've been trying to create a class to allow me to output core data out to JSON.

I have managed to get it working to a point, however I seem to have hit a brick wall on a outputting relationships

```
NSMutableArray * objectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSManagedObject * object in array) {
    if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:object]) {
        [objectsArray addObject:object];
    } else {

    NSMutableDictionary *fields = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSAttributeDescription *attribute in [[object entity] properties]) {
        NSString *attributeName = attribute.name;
        id attributeValue = [object valueForKey:attributeName];

        if([results length] > 0)
        {
            NSArray *chunks2 = [results componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
            for (NSString * string in chunks2) {
                if([string.lowercaseString isEqualToString:attributeName.lowercaseString])
                {
                    [fields setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",attributeValue] forKey:attributeName];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (attributeValue) {
                [fields setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",attributeValue] forKey:attributeName];
            }
        }
    }
    [objectsArray addObject:fields];
    }
}

NSError *error;
NSData * JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:objectsArray options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

And this outputs data fine aslong as I do not have a relationship for example a one -> many or many -> one

It outputs the following

```
{
"mySegmentation": "(null)",
"number": "9452062"
},
{
"mySegmentation": "<NSManagedObject: 0x212050b0> (entity: SegmentationCodes; id: 0x212090b0 <x-coredata://BEC52F5F-EA26-4CFF-BCCB-09DA163F465D/SegmentationCodes/p13> ; data: <fault>)",
"number": "9448502"
},
```

How can I get it to also indent in and output the information from the relationship?

I have been scratching my head for a while on this and would appreciate the help

Thanks Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:

- The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
- All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,
  NSDictionary, or NSNull.
- All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
- Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

So, what you have to do is compose a dictionary or array with dictionaries, arrays, strings, numbers, nulls.

Normally relationships in CoreData are not sorted, so NSSets, you have to generate a NSArray from the set (therefor a nice method from Apple exists) and put it as value in the dictionary for the specific key.

Then run `- dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` for example (as you did before) and retrieve the correct JSON.

Not sure if the indention is right. You have to check that out.

Thats it, hopefully